# How to Prevent TStrings.SaveToStream from writing the BOM?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe3, tstringlist

I am using Delphi XE3.

In my code, I will need to create a file stream, and then write some my own data, as well as the contents of several TStringList into it. The file is in UTF-16LE format.

Therefore, my code:

```
FileStream := TFileStream.Create('D:\MyFile.dat', fmCreate or fmOpenWrite or fmShareExclusive);

try
  // Write some data to FileStream

  // Write contents of StringList1 into FileStream
  StringList1.SaveToStream(FileStream, TEncoding.Unicode);

  // Write some more data to FileStream

  // Write contents of StringList2 into FileSteram
  StringList2.SaveToStream(FileStream, TEncoding.Unicode);
finally
  FileStream.Free;
end;
```

After executing the codes, I find a problem, each time I invoke StringList1.SaveToStream(FileStream, TEncoding.Unicode); it will write BOM (0xFFFE) then followed by the actual strings in the string list.

Therefore, I get a Unicode file like this:

0xFFFE(The first one is written by myself)

(some data)

0xFFFE (StringList1 contents)

(some data)

0xFFFE (StringList2 contents)

But this is not I expect since there should be only one 0xFFFE at the beginning of the file. Therefore, I just wonder how to prevent StringList1.SaveToStream to write the 0xFFFE BOM before writing the actual string lists?

Comment: Stop writing with SaveToStream every time. Use one TStringList, call AddStrings to add the contents of the others, and then save the original using SaveToStream once.

Comment: @KenWhite that will still write a BOM to the stream, which the OP doesn't want at all since he writes his own BOM before writing the TStringList data

Comment: @RemyLebeau: But the posetr does not need to write the BOM, as it's the same one that the SL would write. This is jumping through unnecessary hoops to do what the SL will do for you, and there's no point in doing so.

Comment: @KenWhite if you read the OP's question again more carefully, be writes his own BOM, then some data, THEN a TStringList, then some more data, THEN another TStringList. So what you describe won't work

Comment: @KenWhite, RemyLebeau is correct. I need to write the mixed of my own data as well as the contents of TStringList into the stream. Therefore, put everything into TStringList is not feasible. Also my contents are huge(20 - 30 MB+), it will consume a lot of memory if all put in TStringList. I also revised my post to make it more clear.

Comment: @alancc: Your data is still text, if you're putting it into a file that has a BOM. And using one stringlist that holds 20 MB of data is no more memory-intensive than using 4 stringlists that each hold 5 MB (in fact, it's less memory load, as you have three less object instances by using one). You can write your data, add strings, write your data, add strings, etc., and then just write it out at the end. No matter, though - if Remy's answer solves your problem, that's enough. You haven't marked it as accepted, though, or even upvoted it.

Comment: @KenWhite, Thank you for your explanation. Yes, if all data comes from Delphi and they are textual, then TStringList should be OK. However, some of my data comes from a file that is generated by a C++ DLL. And the file is a bit large, so I choose not to load all of its contents into memory, instead, I just copy its data to the final destination file via CopyFrom.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I find another solution for my question.

TStrings has a WriteBOM property, which will control whether to write out the BOM when using SaveToStream or SaveToFile.

Therefore, using the following codes will disable the BOM:

```
  StringList1.WriteBOM := False;
  StringList1.SaveToStream(FileStream, TEncoding.Unicode);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `SaveToStream()` to save to a `TMemoryStream` first, then set that stream's `Position` to skip past the BOM in it and save the rest of its data to the `TFileStream`.

```pascal
procedure WriteUnicodeStrings(AStream: TStream; AStrings: TStrings);
var
  MS: TMemoryStream;
begin
  MS := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    AStrings.SaveToStream(MS, TEncoding.Unicode);
    if MS.Size > 2 then
    begin
      MS.Position := 2;
      AStream.CopyFrom(MS, MS.Size-2);
    end;
  finally
    MS.Free;
  end;
end;
...
FileStream := TFileStream.Create('D:\MyFile.dat', fmCreate or fmOpenWrite or fmShareExclusive);
try
  // Write some data to FileStream
  WriteUnicodeStrings(FileStream, StringList1);
  // Write some more data to FileStream
  WriteUnicodeStrings(FileStream, StringList2);
finally
  FileStream.Free;
end;
```

Or, you can simply derive a class from `SysUtils.TUnicodeEncoding` and override its `GetPreamble()` method to not return any BOM, then use that class instead of using `TEncoding.Unicode`.

```pascal
type
  TMyUnicodeEncoding = class(TUnicodeEncoding)
  public
    function GetPreamble: TBytes; override;
  end;

function TMyUnicodeEncoding.GetPreamble: TBytes;
begin
  Result := nil;
end;

procedure WriteUnicodeStrings(AStream: TStream; AStrings: TStrings);
var
  Enc: TMyUnicodeEncoding;
begin
  Enc := TMyUnicodeEncoding.Create;
  try
    AStrings.SaveToStream(AStream, Enc);
  finally
    Enc.Free;
  end;
end;
...
FileStream := TFileStream.Create('D:\MyFile.dat', fmCreate or fmOpenWrite or fmShareExclusive);
try
  // Write some data to FileStream
  WriteUnicodeStrings(FileStream, StringList1);
  // Write some more data to FileStream
  WriteUnicodeStrings(FileStream, StringList2);
finally
  FileStream.Free;
end;
```

Comment: I read the document on GetPreamble and it is said "If no preamble is required, a zero length array is returned.". But you return nil. I think it does not mean a 0 length array, it indicates a nil pointer. However, your codes can be compiled under Delphi. Why?

Comment: @alancc `TBytes` is a dynamic `array of Byte`. A 0-length dynamic array is represented by a nil pointer (just like with `string`). You can use `SetLength(Result, 0);` instead of `Result := nil;` but the end result would be the same at runtime - a nil pointer.